# $(document).scrollTop off by pixels in chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scrolltop

In a rather complex layouted page, I can do this in the chrome console:

```
$(document).scrollTop(800)
[#document]
$(document).scrollTop()
800
$(document).scrollTop(801)
[#document]
$(document).scrollTop()
800
$(document).scrollTop(802)
[#document]
$(document).scrollTop()
801
$(document).scrollTop(799)
[#document]
$(document).scrollTop()
798
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I let the thing scroll to where *I* want it ?

Comment: So you're saying that 1 pixel off is critical ?

Comment: Can you explain more about this "complex layout"? (Ideally make a reduced test case). It looks to me like 800 is the maximum scroll position, and that chrome is scrolling in 2-pixel increments (or possibly there is some sub-pixel stuff going on, or another script interfering). Need more details.

Comment: Inside the page, there are elements that have css transform:scale. the body or html arent scaled. It happens with all other scripts turned off. The page is > 3000px high. I couldnt repeat this in a reduced test case ...

Comment: Yes, the 1 pixel is critical. Creates a very visible ugly line in the design, plus, by not being aligned, it triggers an auto scroll, which doesnt scroll to the right place, which triggers a autoscroll, .. etc. I'm blocking that now by saying 'never mind the pixel'.